# Upgrade MySQL and innodb_file_per_table

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.5, mysql-5.6

I'd like to upgrade MySQL version from 5.5 to 5.6.
I know that one of the differences is that in 5.6 innodb_file_per_table is set to true.
What will be the best practice of upgrading MySQL while preserving the existing data?
I saw in many places that the recommended way to upgrade is to create a backup to the data dir, and after the upgrade return the data dir instead of the new one.
But then I will still have one innodb file for the entire DB instead of for each table.
I do want this feature (of having different innnodb file per table), so setting innodb_file_per_table to false for the new 5.6 version is not an option.

Comment: What is your primary goal with the upgrade? Do you want to minimize downtime, or is that not a concern?

Comment: Well, it depends, if we are talking about minutes vs hours, it might be a consideration. Can you elaborate?

Comment: One possibility would be to set up streaming replication from your existing installation to a new 5.6 installation with the mentioned slight differences in setup for the innodb tables, let it catch up completely, then in a very short downtime, switch the connection properties around to the new server. It minimizes downtime, but it costs parallel setups.

Comment: That sounds like a very good idea! How quick do you think the replication will stream the data to the new version?

Comment: That depends on the used solution as well as on the amount of data and cannot be guessed. If you have this option, I'd try it if the dataset is not too large.